# Python authorizing into Google - getting referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, google-drive-api

This code has been working for a while and suddenly this morning it started throwing a 'reference before assignment' error but I am not sure why that is being thrown. The error is happening at this line `creds.refresh(Request())` on the `creds` var:

```
def getAuth(self):

    try:
    
        creds = None
        errMsg = "There was an error authenticating to Google. The token is not valid."

        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.

        if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            print(f"{cm.WARNING}No creds or creds are not valid...{cm.ENDC}")
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                print(f"{cm.WARNING}Refreshing token...{cm.ENDC}")
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                credsPath = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/xxxxxx/Development/Python/xxxxxxxx/modules/credentials.json") 
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credsPath, SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        #validate auth
        if creds.valid == False:
            return {"success":False, "error-message":errMsg}
        else:
            return {"success":True, "credentials": creds}

    except Exception as e: 
        return {"success":False, "error-message":f"{cm.WARNING}There was an error getting Google authorization\n{e}{cm.ENDC}"}
```

The error messages is:

> local variable 'creds' referenced before assignment.

To add to this, I can print out `creds` before the `creds.refresh(Request())` call:

> <google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object at 0x110097c70>

What can I try next?

Comment: Post the full error. WHAT is being referenced before assignment?

Comment: @Daviid - LOL, I literally was adding it I guess while you were typing your question. See the edits. Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Werid, it should work. Maybe there's some identation problem?

Comment: Where here does Request() comes from ?

Comment: I would suggest start removing stuff not related to `creds` and see if you can keep reproducing the error. Like, remove the try except, replace `Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)` for a dict or something, etc... And whenever the error goes away backtrack and remove something else.

Comment: LOL, stop typing what I am doing. : D See my answer below. Thanks for helping out, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. I deleted the token.json file so the script would create a new one. I had added additional scopes to the app and this seems to have broken things.